# Can I map custom Abbreviations to a keyboard shortcut in Goland IDE?

Tags: go, goland

In emacs I use custom abbreviations all the time. Unfortunately I am being "asked" to use Goland as an IDE in my new position. I'd like to map the text:

```golang
if err != nil {

}
```

and place the cursor in that block. Is that possible with goland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/using-live-templates.html) and [Postfix Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion).

GoLand has `err` by default.

[image]